# Can I retrieve tags assigned to an email when sending with AWS SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm using **AMAZON SES** to send emails and **AMAZON SNS** to subscribe to a hook and receive personalized notifications (When an email is delivered, bounced or rejected, basically).

The point here is that I'm trying to filter email types. When sending an email, I'm adding a Tag to it, for example: 'recoverEmail'. With this, when I receive the delivery notification on my hook, I know exactly where I should look for the transaction record to update it properly.

I can't find anything searching, even within the docs. This is What I'm passing as params:

```js
const params = {
  EmailTags: [{
    Name: 'emailType',
    Value: 'recoverPassword',
  }],
  Destination: {
    ToAddresses: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [email] : [EmailSender.SANDBOX_EMAIL_TO],
  },
  Content: {
    Simple: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Data: text,
        },
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: `Recover your password for ${email} account`,
      },
    },
  },
  FromEmailAddress: EmailSender.EMAIL_FROM,
};
```

It properly works and send the email, but when I receive the delivery notification, the tag is not present anywhere:

```js
{
  headers: {
    host: 'xxxxxxxxx.ngrok.io',
    'user-agent': 'Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent',
    'content-length': '1682',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'x-amz-sns-message-id': 'xxxxxxx-670f-5f63-9dc9-xxxxxxxxx',
    'x-amz-sns-message-type': 'Notification',
    'x-amz-sns-subscription-arn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx-email-xxxxxx:yyyyyyyy-df21-478c-aaaaa-xxxxxxxxxx',
    'x-amz-sns-topic-arn': 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxx-email-xxxxxxx',
    'x-forwarded-for': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'x-forwarded-proto': 'https'
  },
  type: 'Notification',
  timestamp: '2023-04-14T04:45:57.113Z',
  message: {
    notificationType: 'Delivery',
    mail: {
      timestamp: '2023-04-14T04:45:55.792Z',
      source: 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com',
      sourceArn: 'arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:identity/xxxxxxxx.com',
      sourceIp: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      callerIdentity: 'xxxx-api-xxxxxx',
      sendingAccountId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      messageId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-7e9a-4bc3-b4f7-xxxxxxxxx-000000',
      destination: [Array]
    },
    delivery: {
      timestamp: '2023-04-14T04:45:57.046Z',
      processingTimeMillis: 1254,
      recipients: [Array],
      smtpResponse: '250 2.0.0 OK  1681447557 i14-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.127 - gsmtp',
      remoteMtaIp: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
      reportingMTA: 'a8-97.smtp-out.amazonses.com'
    }
  },
```

If somebody know the trick on this, would be verrrrryyy helpfull for me.

I tried several web search and docs review. I haven't found anything that can help.

Comment: @MarceloPaco Thanks. I've already changed the images for codeblocks.